# A few years ago / until a few years ago

Tags: differences

What's the difference between having **until** and without **until** in the following context.

> **Until** a few years ago, the prevailing model was based on recycling: The brain got rid of its own waste, not only beta-amyloid but other metabolites, by breaking it down and recycling it at an individual cell level.

Thank you!

Comment: The inclusion of _until_ implies that the situation being described _ended_ a few years ago.

Comment: What about a few years ago? Does it mean we don't know whether it's prevailling now or not?

Comment: It simply states what the situation was then - implying, but not saying, that it is different now.

Comment: Until say 2015 vs round about 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until = “up to (the time that)”

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/until)

All we know for sure from this sentence is that ***During a period** that ended at the time that was a few years ago, the model prevailed*. The implication is that at that time something changed so that the model no longer prevailed. In normal usage the implication would be confirmed (or denied) by either or both of the preceding or following statements.

If *until* is removed, the sentence states that ***At or around that time** that was a few years ago, the model prevailed*. It tells us nothing else. As above, there may be an implication that other models prevailed before or after that time, but these implications may only be confirmed (or denied) by preceding or following statements.